# QObject::connect no matching function

Tags: c++, qt, connection, qobject

```
chip_definition/Isrc/NLBChipDefinitionEditor.C:20: error: no matching function for call to `nlb::gui::chip_definition::ChipDefinitionEditor::connect(QAction*, const char*, nlb::gui::chip_definition::ChipDefinitionEditor* const, const char*)'
```

Im getting this error from the code:

```
   qDebug() << dynamic_cast<QObject*>(this);
    connect(m_engine->actionRegister().actionAt(nlb::gui::base::ACTION_ID_CONTEXT_REMOVE_CHIP), SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(onRemoveSelectedChips()));
```

Error states that `this(ChipDefinitionEditor*)` is not `QObject*` but `dynamic_cast` casts ok when `connect` is commented. `ChipDefinitionEditor` is derived from `QObject` of course. How could this happen?

Comment: Have you placed the Q_OBJECT macro inside the class declaration for ChipDefinitionEditor? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT

Comment: @CoryKlein Yes Q_OBJECT is written too

Comment: What if you try `QObject *object = dynamic_cast<QObject*>(this)` then connect to `object`? Does that at least get it to work? You'd have to connect it to a generic `QObject` signal of course, in this case.

Comment: One other thing you could try is rather than just using `connect(...)` you could specify it as `QObject::connect(...)`. That might get it to work.

Comment: After doing what you suggested Iam getting `error: no matching function for call to nlb::gui::chip_definition::ChipDefinitionEditor::connect(QAction*, const char*, QObject*&, const char*)'`

Comment: Is that after doing the dynamic cast or the `QObject::connect(...)`?

Comment: It is after doing both.

Comment: Have you included `QAction`?

Comment: @RA It worked after included QAction. Thank you. Can you explain why it doesn't complain about QAction ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt expects that the arguments to `connect` be of type `QObject*`.  Given an error of this form:

```
no matching function for call to `connect(SOMETYPE*, const char*, 
                                          SOMEOTHERTYPE*, const char*)'
```

The compiler is implicitly stating that it doesn't have information indicating that `SOMETYPE` and `SOMEOTHERTYPE` is a `QObject` given what has been included for that translation unit.  Often times, simply including the header file for `SOMETYPE`/`SOMEOTHERTYPE` provides the compiler with what it needs to determine that `SOMETYPE`/`SOMEOTHERTYPE` inherits from `QObject`.  In other cases (such as yours), you need to ensure that `SOMETYPE`/`SOMEOTHERTYPE` has been dynamically cast to a `QObject`.

It's also worth noting that when the compiler has adequate information for one type but not the other, the error message changes slightly.  For example, if you fix the error for `SOMETYPE` but not `SOMEOTHERTYPE`, the error message changes slightly:

```
no matching function for call to `connect(QObject*, const char*, 
                                          SOMEOTHERTYPE*, const char*)'
```